# fixing metadata if destination file is younger than source file

Tags: file-copy, timestamps

I guess the question first has to learn from your comments, before it grows into a grown-up question.

Here is the tricky situation:
I have a folder destination with many files (pdfs), that, unfortunately, have the same, recent, timestamp (date of last change of file). However, these timestamps are wrong, they merely reflect a date of copying. I have also a backup folder, the source, with some of these files, with their older timestamps.

Now I wish to have the old timestamp on my destination folder IFF the destination file and the source file are otherwise the same.

How to fix the metadata of those files at the destination that are younger than the same file at the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't really want to copy the files at all, but just fix up the metadata (date).

Accordingly you can use something like this:

```
rsync --dry-run -av --existing --size-only src/ dst
```

The directories `src` and `dst` are the source and intended destination directories. When you're happy it looks like it's going to work, remove the `--dry-run` flag.

Note that the `--size-only` flag tells `rsync` to compare only by file size (and name). It does not check the content of each file. If you want to check the content you might as well just copy the correct files in the first place